# The action of the torus $T_N$ on the semigroup algebra $C[M]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Toric Varieties written by David Cox, John Little and Hal Schenck
p.18 Equivalence of constructions

Before starting our main result, we need to study the action of the torus $T_N$ on the semigroup algebra $C[M]$. The action of the torus $T_N$ on itself given by multiplication induces an action on $C[M]$ as follows: if $t \in T_N$ and $f \in C[M]$, then $t*f \in C[M]$ is defined by $p \mapsto f(t^{-1}*p)$ for $p \in V$. The minus sign will be explained in 5.0.

I cannot undestand this definition. What does this mean?
My teacher said that the V in the passage above is a mistake.

Comment: $$ is an affine toric variety (as in Definition 1.1.3) and ${\mathbb C}[M]$ is the coordinate ring of the torus $_$ acting on $V$. Thus, $f\in {\mathbb C}[M]$ is a regular map and $∗\in {\mathbb C}[M]$ is the regular map given by $(∗)()=(^{−1})$ for $$ a point of the torus $_$. Note that the coordinate algebra ${\mathbb C}[V]$ of the toric variety $V$ can be regarded as a subalgebra of ${\mathbb C}[M]$] and for the action $T_N\times V\rightarrow V$ you may take $\in $.

Comment: Why is f∈C[M] regarded as a regular map? Is V an arbitrary toric variety?

Comment: $C[M]$ is the coordinate algebra of the affine torus $T_N$; by definition its elements are regular maps $f:T_N\rightarrow {\mathbb C}$. And $V$ is not an arbitrary toric variety: it is an affine toric variety over ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Then V is an arbitrary affine toric variety or a specific affine toric variety?